# How to iterate over multiple objects and remove a certain property

Tags: javascript, object

I'd like to preface this by saying I'm very new to coding (sorry if this is a very straightforward query - but it has me stumped!)

I'm trying to iterate through objects for the first time and delete a specified key-value pair.

I have a function with an array of User objects and within that array I want to delete the person's name from each object.

I've tried iterating through the object using the .length property but  get the result `Reference Error: name is not defined.`

When I try the following it works (but this isn't ideal as I want the code to run without having the specify the individual index number):

```
delete users[0].name; 
delete users[1].name; 

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i] === name) {
        users.splice(i, 1); 
     }
    return users;  
}
```

Actual result: `ReferenceError: name is not defined`
I want the result to remove the name: ' ' value from the object.

Comment: There’s only one code block visible in the question, but do you mean `delete users[0].name; delete users[1].name;` does what you want when there are two users and you’d like to convert that to a loop?

Comment: The error means you do not have the `name` variable defined. You need something like `var name = 'Kate';` if you want to delete the user inside the array whose name is Kate. At the moment your `if()` check does not know what name you are trying to remove. It would help if you show the users array as well.

Comment: when you use splice it deletes the complete object from the array not just the property, which also reduces the size of array. so everytime you splice the array you must add i--;

Comment: Or just save the length in a variable before the loop instead of evaluating the `.length` every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate the array and delete the unwanted propery. This mutates the given data.

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    delete users[i].name;
}
```

An advanced version takes a destructuring with the unwanted property and a rest syntax for getting all other properties and return this object.

```
users = users.map(({ name, ...object }) => object);
```

Comment: That thing `users = users.map(({ name, ...object }) => object);` is soo good

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to loop over the items using `forEach` and delete the desired property.

```
let users = [{name: "a", prop1: 1, prop2: 2},{name: "b", prop1: 2, prop2: 2}, {name: "c", prop1: 3, prop2: 2}];


users.forEach(user => {
  delete user['name'];
}); 

console.log("after deleting property", users);
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the key-value pair...

```
var users = [
  {name: "John", role: "Cleaner"},
  {name: "Jim", role: "Sergent"},
  {name: "Jackhn", role: "Baker"},
  {name: "Josh", role: "tinker"},
  {name: "Jenny", role: "Soldier"}
];

for (var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {
  delete users[i].name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> There’s only one code block visible in the question, but do you mean `delete users[0].name; delete users[1].name;` does what you want when there are two users and you’d like to convert that to a loop?

If yes,

```
for (let user of users) {
    delete user.name;
}
```

That loops over every user in the array and deletes the `name` property of each one.